# Need to click a text from the dropdown menu to change the default option in the dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to python and selenium webdriver. The sample structure of html code is

```html
<li class="dropdown env-dropdown">
   ::before
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="">
     <i class="nav-icon fa fa-plug">
       ::before
     </i>
     <span id="configured-env">ENVNAME1</span>
   </a>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu env-dropdown-menu env-menu-scroll">
 <input id="selectedEnv" name="envConfigV0.userPreference.env.environmentId" value="" type="hidden>

     <li>
      <div class="spinner-container" style="display:block;"> </div>
        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin spinner-tsg"></i>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li class="env-data">
       <a id="environmentList0" class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="confirmEnvironmentChange{0}" href="#" data-toggle="modal">
        ENVNAME0
        <input id ="environmentId0" name="#env.name" value="11" type="hidden">
       </a>
     </li>
     <li class="env-data divider"></li>
     
     <li class="env-data">
       <a id="environmentList2" class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="confirmEnvironmentChange{2}" href="#" data-toggle="modal">
        ENVNAME2
        <input id ="environmentId2" name="#env.name" value="6" type="hidden">
       </a>
     </li>
     <li class="env-data divider"></li>

     <li class="env-data">
       <a id="environmentList3" class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="confirmEnvironmentChange{3}" href="#" data-toggle="modal">
        ENVNAME3
        <input id ="environmentId3" name="#env.name" value="9" type="hidden">
       </a>
     </li>
     <li class="env-data divider"></li>
    </ul>
    ::after
   </li>
```

The default configured-env is ENVNAME1 under the dropdown env-dropdown. I was able to hover over the dropdown menu by using the following code:

```
env_dropdown = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class = "dropdown env-dropdown"]')
ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(env_dropdown).perform()
```

I want to change the configured-env to ENVNAME2 by clicking on the text "ENVNAME2". But I was not able to achieve this after trying various options. Request you to please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This drop down is not made using select and options tags. So , select class from selenium will not work.

Workaround would be :

1. Click on drop down using selenium
2. Store every element in a list and and one by one match it with your required text. If match happens , then just click on it.

I'm providing the code for 2, you can write your own code for 1st part.

```
drop_down = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.env-data a")
for values in  drop_down:
  if values.text==ENVNAME2:
    values.click()
```

Comment: This code will lead to `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Andersson : changed to `find_elements`. Thanks Anyways.

Comment: @cruisepandey and Andersson Thanks a lot for your help. The code worked for me.     env_dropdown = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class = "dropdown env-dropdown"]')
    ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(env_dropdown).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    drop_down = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.env-data a")
    for values in drop_down:
        if values.text == "ENVNAME2":
            values.click()

Answer (score 1):

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class = 'dropdown env-dropdown']/option[text()='YOUR_NAME_ELEMENT_OF_LIST']").click()
```

in any case are you sure that it's a drop-down menu?
generally the drop-down menu html is something like this:

```
<select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Your example looks more a list item:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp

Comment: Nah, this won't work. As HTML shared by OP , Drop down is not build using select and options tag.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have solved lot of problems using javascript. You can try and see if this is working

```
 driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('configured-env')='ENVNAME2'")
```